# Singularities/infinities of continuity equation in polar coordinate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, singularities, diffusion

I encountered a bit of a difficulty in solving the continuity equation for polar coordinates. For a "fluid" or density of particles moving radially outwards with constant velocity, its flux should be $\vec{j} = |V| \rho \hat{r}$, and the continuity equation is

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \vec{j} = sources-sinks.$$

For 2d polar coordinates and radial flow only, the equation becomes

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r\rho|V|) = sources - sinks.$$

For no sources or sinks, the utmost general solution must look like

$\frac{f(r-vt)}{r}$

But this is where I have a conceptual difficulty, unless f(-vt)=0, this solution must be infinite at the origin which seems unphysical. If I deliberately force an initial condition, such as a gaussian distribution at $t=0$, the solution becomes

$\frac{e^{-(r-tV)^2s^2/2}(r-tV)}{r}$

While this matches the general form of above, the results are totally unphysical, especially since this is supposed to model a *density*. At t=0, it matches the initial condition, but then for t>0, there are domains of negative values, the singularity at the origin.

I looked into this a bit, and the continuity equation seems to be defined only in regions that do not contain sources or sinks, but even in the case without, there are issues in this equation. What is going on here? Am I not accounting for something?

Answer (score 0):

Entering your "utmost general solution" on the left-hand side does not yield a zero, but
$$
\frac{f(r-vt)\left|V\right|}{r^2}\,.
$$
(Assuming constant velocity. With non-constant velocity we get an additional $\frac{f(r-vt)\partial_r \left|V\right|}{r}$, which maybe could be used to construct a radius-dependend velocity profile that makes the LHS vanish by requiring $\left|V\right| + r \partial_r \left|V\right| = 0$.)

There are instances of continuity equations that preserve positivity of the solution. The Fokker-Planck equation can be such an example when one defines the probability current properly (note that then we have used more info than just the continuity equation!). But in general there is no such requirement: The best example is electrodynamics, where you have a continuity equation for the charge density that can attain both positive and negative values.

Comment: I've been poking around this a bit more and am tempted to reask the question in a different way, but perhaps you could clarify some aspects of your solution. Why would the continuity equation ever provide negative solutions? You mention preserving positivity. For 2d polar coordinates with constant velocity radial outflow, assuming there is a gaussian distribution to the initial density, the analytic solution I obtain from Mathematica permits negative values for radii greater than 0 which seems unphysical to me

Comment: Continuity, conservation of some quantity can mean that you take it away from place 1 and move it to place 2 - let's say sand on the beach: If you use a mass density describing the sand deposited above level ground and start with level ground $\rho = 0$ then by digging a hole and throwing the sand somewhere else, you end up with a place (the hole) with negative density. Mass conservation would still hold in this process, so we have a solution of the continuity equation.

Comment: The continuity equation alone does not provide a unique solution: In fluid dynamics, for example, you solve the continuity equation together with the momentum balance equation (and whatever else you need, depending on the complexity of the problem). Or, for example, there are (infinitely) many time-dependent probability densities that satisfy a continuity equation, but only one among them that solves the equation you get once you provide a closure for the probability current (and end up with a Fokker-Planck equation, for example).